# Highcharts - kind of hack for stick plot timeseries

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi all from a highchart developer [Pawel-fus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451635/pawel-fus) on [Highcharts official forum](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/is-it-possible-to-create-stick-plot-in-highchart-t29049/), I came to know that highchart doesn't support stick plot, and similar effects can be achieved using linked series.

I have u and v components which I want to show as stick using highcharts, So theoretically what I know is

**A stick plot is a plot on the u-v plane.  Suppose you have a time
series of a vector (u(t), v(t)).  Then, you plot line segments
  from (c*t, 0) to (c*t+u(t), v(t))
on the u-v plane for all values of t, where c is an arbitrary
constant.  Each line segment represents the vector (u(t), v(t))
but its origin is shifted as (c*t, 0).
So, the vertical axis is v and the horizontal axis is u.
But, the horizontal axis is "labeled" with time t, just for
convenience, to represent the shift of the origin (c*t,0).**

from **Pawel-Fus** help, I could able to implement theory like this, here x axis is numeric that is 0 - 3, **checkout** [Fiddle - working theory](http://jsfiddle.net/VtV7N/)

```
     <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
     <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>

     <script>


     $(function () {
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
             chart: {
                 renderTo: 'container'
             },
             colors: ['blue'],
             plotOptions: {
                 series: {
                     marker: {
                         enabled: false
                     }
                 }
             },

             series: [{
                 name: 'main',
                 id: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [0, 0],
                     [(-3.969 +0), -1.001]
                 ]
             }, {
                 name: 'main',
                 linkedTo: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [1, 0],
                     [(-4.578 + 1), 0.596]
                 ]
             }, {
                 name: 'main',
                 linkedTo: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [2, 0],
                     [(1.593 + 2), 0.484]
                 ]
             }, {
                 name: 'main',
                 linkedTo: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [3, 0],
                     [(-1.622 + 3), 1.580]
                 ]
             }]
         });
     });
     </script>
```

but my ultimate aim is to make **time series plot**, so I tried like this, here I replaced with date, unfortunately I didn't get result like above **checkout** [Bad Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDf4Z/)

```
     <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
     <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>

     <script>


     $(function () {
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
             chart: {
                 renderTo: 'container'
             },
             colors: ['blue'],
             plotOptions: {
                 series: {
                     marker: {
                         enabled: false
                     }
                 }
             },

     xAxis: {


         type: 'datetime',

        dateTimeLabelFormats : {

                    year: '%e %b %Y',

                 }
     },
             series: [{
                 name: 'main',
                 id: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [Date.UTC(1982, 1, 16), 0],
                     [(-3.969 + Date.UTC(1982, 1, 16)), -1.001]
                 ]
             }, {
                 name: 'main',
                 linkedTo: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [Date.UTC(1982, 2, 16), 0],
                     [(-4.578 + Date.UTC(1982, 2, 16)), 0.596]
                 ]
             }, {
                 name: 'main',
                 linkedTo: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [Date.UTC(1982, 3, 16), 0],
                     [(1.593 + Date.UTC(1982, 3, 16)), 0.484]
                 ]
             }, {
                 name: 'main',
                 linkedTo: 'main',
                 data: [
                     [Date.UTC(1982, 4, 16), 0],
                     [(-1.622 + Date.UTC(1982, 4, 16)), 1.580]
                 ]
             }]
         });

     });
     </script>
```

So what I am doing wrong with time series plot ? whether timeseries can be done like first working script ? and I want to add arrow for each stick on top

Someone please help me...

Please shout at me, if you need more clarification...

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates are too close to get any sort of slope to your line.  Date.UTC returns milliseconds since 1/1/1970, so subtracting off only 3 or 4 milliseconds, will just produce vertical lines. This:

```
data: [
    [Date.UTC(1982, 1, 16), 0],
    [(-3.969 + Date.UTC(1982, 1, 16)), -1.001]
]
```

is equal to:

```
data: [
    [382665600000, 0],
    [382665599996.031, -1.001]
]
```

Comment: Just like Mark said - you have really close values. Second thing is that each data series should be sorted ascending.

Comment: @Mark:  Hi I found prototype written by you to draw arrow for line plot, I have tried to use the same to complete code, for type scatter, though arrow is coming,but its orientation is wrong sometimes may be due to the fact that I am trying to implement for scatter type...  please see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493584/how-to-add-arrow-to-end-of-line-while-using-type-scatter