# How to add arrow to end of line while using type scatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How do I add arrow to every end of line properly where y is not equal to zero, and series type is scatter with linewidth 2, here I can see arrow is added but its not properly added,

**Please see this** [Partially working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnYCX/)

This is my JS,originally prototype is written by stackoverflow's top contributor [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16363/mark)

```
 $(function () {
  var lineSeries = Highcharts.seriesTypes.scatter;


var lineDrawGraph = lineSeries.prototype.drawGraph;
lineSeries.prototype.drawGraph = function() {

    var arrowLength = 15,
        arrowWidth = 9,
        series = this,
        segments = series.linedata || series.segments,
        lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
        lastPoint = lastSeg[lastSeg.length - 1],
        nextLastPoint = lastSeg[lastSeg.length - 2],
        angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
        (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY)),
        path = [];

        angle = Math.PI+angle;

    lineDrawGraph.apply(series, arguments);

    path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

    if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX)
    {
        path.push(
            'L',
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        );
        path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        );
        path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
            'Z'
        );
    }
    else
    {        
        path.push(
            'L',
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        );
        path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        );
        path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
            'Z'
        );
    }

    series.chart.renderer.path(path)
        .attr({
            fill: series.color
        })
        .add(series.group);

};

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'scatter'
},

 plotOptions: {
        series: {
                  animation: {
                               duration: 2000
                             },
                  lineWidth: 2,
           marker: {
                enabled: false
                }
                },

            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineWidth: 2
                },

        }

          },    

series: [{
        name: 'main',
        id: 'main',
        data: [
            [0, 0],
            [(-3.969 +0), -1.001]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'main',
        linkedTo: 'main',
        data: [
            [1, 0],
            [(-4.578 +1), 0.596]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'main',
        linkedTo: 'main',
        data: [
            [2, 0],
            [(1.593 + 2), 0.484]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'main',
        linkedTo: 'main',
        data: [
            [3, 0],
            [(-1.622 + 3), 1.580]
        ]
    }]
  });


  });
```

Please Help..

Thanks Mark for sharing code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the scatter that's messing you up; it's the fact that your data is not properly sorted.  Highcharts expects input data to be **sorted by x value**:

```
data: [
    [0, 0],
    [(-3.969 +0), -1.001]
].sort() // this is wrong order, I added sort...
```

Also, you'll need to apply the fix to my orginal code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22842988/16363).

Putting this together, here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnYCX/1/).

Comment: I need to put arrow when y is not zero since its stick plot..that is why I didn't sort

Comment: But sorted data is required.

Comment: @Peter, as SebastianBochan says, Highcharts requires sorted data.  With that in mind see updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vnYCX/4/; this will test the two points, put the arrow on the **non** zero y value.  I think I have the trigonometry worked out correctly :)

Comment: @Mark: Absolutely your trigonometry is working, I have one more query, suppose if I use `zoomType: 'xy'`, how do I update arrow ? how to call prototype on change ?  http://jsfiddle.net/qFSZd/

Comment: In the simples way, you can catch [redraw event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw), destroy all arrows and create new one.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, this actually looks like a bug in the latest version of Highcharts.  I thought this line `.add(series.group)` is supposed to add it to the series element's child nodes, all of which should be cleared when the series is re-drawn.  See this updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vnYCX/5/, where I've rewritten the extension according to the newer api documented here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Problem is with code in wrapper. You need to manage arrows on your own, Highcharts won't do this for you. Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/vnYCX/7/

Comment: @Mark the fiddle link is not working