# Risk HeatMap using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm working on "Risk HeatMap" refer below image(ignore bubbles). So far I'm able do the heatmap refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/517/).
 Please guide me on how to Add Arrows on top of Highcharts i.e Vector Chart. 
Sample Code for Color in Each Cell:

```js
events: {
  load: function() {
    var points = this.series[0].data,
      lenY = this.yAxis[0].tickPositions.length - 1,
      lenX = this.xAxis[0].tickPositions.length - 1,
      x = lenX,
      tmpX = 0,
      y = 0,
      j = 0;

    $.each(points, function(i, p) {

      if (p.x == 0 || p.y == 0) {
        p.update({
          color: 'red'
        }, false);
      } else if (p.x > 0 && p.y > 0 && (p.y == x || (p.y + 1) == x)) {
        p.update({
          color: 'green'
        }, false);

        if (p.y == x)
          x--;

      } else if (p.x > 1 && p.y > 0 && p.y > x) {
        p.update({
          color: 'orange'
        }, false);
      } else if (p.x > 0 && p.y > 0 && x > 2) {
        p.update({
          color: 'yellow'
        }, false);
      }

    });

    this.isDirty = true;
    this.redraw();
  }
}
```

[image: "Risk Heatmap"]

Comment: To add custom elements, like bubbles and arrows, you could use Highcharts' [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) For bubbles you could use bubble type series - http://jsfiddle.net/10vfg03o/

Comment: Hi @KacperMadej I need to implement directed Arrows(ignore bubbles from image) refer this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/519/). I've gone through the Renderer but not sure how to implement in my scenario. Any guidance on this will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add arrows to ends of lines in series you could use following wrapper:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getContainer', function(proceed) {
      proceed.apply(this);

      var chart = this,
        renderer = chart.renderer,
        defOptions = chart.options.defs || [],
        i = defOptions.length,
        def,
        D;

      while (i--) {
        def = defOptions[i];
        var D = renderer.createElement('marker').attr({
          id: def.id,
          viewBox: "0 0 10 10",
          refX: 1,
          refY: 5,
          markerWidth: 6,
          markerHeight: 6,
          orient: 'auto',
          fill: 'inherit',
        }).add(renderer.defs);
        renderer.createElement('path').attr({
          d: def.path,
          fill: 'white'
        }).add(D);
      }
    });

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {
      proceed.apply(this);
      if (this.options.endMarker) {
        this.graph.element.setAttribute('marker-end', this.options.endMarker);
      }
    });
  })(Highcharts);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/w6kqwp9p/

Relevant comment in relevant topic: [How to add arrow to end of line while using type scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493584/how-to-add-arrow-to-end-of-line-while-using-type-scatter/23498405?noredirect=1#comment36120644_23498405)

Comment: superb stuff, is there any way i can add the Scatter chart dynamically using any loops as we get data from DB and thereby not sure how many times we've to repeat the scatter chart.

Comment: @GeekExplorer Yes, to add series dynamically use [chart.addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries).